# How to find the IP Address of HTC Incredible on a CDMA Network

Tags: android, networking, ip-address, wifi, cdma

How can I find the IP address of the an HTC incredible connected to Verizon's network? 
My other question - do I have to make any changes to my App to run it on a cellular network? Till now the App was running on a Nexus One connected to a local Wi-Fi network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Through mobile network, to check your IP run the command below:

```
ifconfig rmnet0
```

or application like 'Android Status' can be handy. Get it from the market.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get IP address info look at this [example](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f7/how-to-display-wifi-ip-address-8599/). Might need a tweak for your CDMA.
2. You need not modify anything to get it working on Mobile n/w

Comment: I know how to get the IP assigned by the Wi-Fi network. I'm interested in the IP that is assigned by the mobile service provider (Verizon in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();, then addresses = intf.getInetAddresses(); to enumerate all the IP addresses on all the interfaces. You're looking for an address associated with a PDP.

That should work.  I'm currently looking for a neater way.

Answer (score 0):

To get the internal IP Address you can use the following snippet of code:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
  NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
  Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();

  while (inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()) {
    InetAddress inetAddress = inetAddresses.nextElement();

    byte[] address = inetAddress.getAddress();
  }
}
```

Note: This will return the private network IP Address.
If you want the public IP Address you will need to use STUN (try jSTUN).

Hope that helps!